# Stub controller method when performing web request with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

How can I stub either the controller method or the helper method that occurs upon making the request?

I have a test that makes a web request. The request goes to the controller which also calls a helper method. In the example below, I want to stub the return value of `service_config` for my testing purposes because `service_config` comes from `AdminsHelper` and performs an actual API request to a service.

I'm a bit new to Rspec and these type of testing practices so I might also be headed the wrong way in proper testing of this web request

Test:

```
context 'when an invalid parameter is specified' do
  it 'should return a hash of size 0' do
    get '/admins/configs/poop'
    json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    expect(json).to be == ({})
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  include AdminsHelper

  def configs
    response = service_config
    render json: response, status: 200
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that [RSpecs any instance mock](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance) would wotk in this case.

```
context 'when an invalid parameter is specified' do
  it 'should return a hash of size 0' do
    allow_any_instance_of(AdminsController).to receive(:service_config).and_return({})

    get '/admins/configs/poop'

    json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    expect(json).to eq({})
 end
```

end